# Generic constraints are ignored when inferring class parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

When a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#generic-classes) is instantiated with `new`, its type parameters are inferred. [Generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) seem to be ignored in this case.

```ts
type MyType = { a?: number, b?: number };

class MyClass<T extends MyType = MyType> {
    constructor(t: T) {}
    method(t: T) {}
}

const myClass1 = new MyClass<MyType>({ a: 1 });
myClass1.method({ b: 1 });


const myClass2 = new MyClass({ a: 1 });
// Why is this error?
// T should extend `MyType` even though type was inferred from a constructor parameter.
myClass2.method({ b: 1 });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8oEMD8AuKAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0UZehpFlUAvgNwBQnAxgDaYAzoNggAwgOEAeeFAgAPYBAIATEXESQoqDUgB86TlGNQeAewKDglIj2BnKACmD54ASnSsjJkhGAALMxVnVw80Ly9eCysoEnFJQQBGbUIIAHdRCSFBKV1IPUcMTHxk1jcuOKzhRIA6XwCgwroStnLuKMtgWPjsgCYUgnTMhKbiqFK2gHpJqAB1fxAoAEsRAJW5SkoHbE5pqFlBQKI+FTlFZVOAAzyIS7kAN2UoBqIAc39npCg0oWWCADMqJQIKd-lsSFhTNFrLZ7CwwJhKJh6lQapxKglenU-IFghgyC0ylwgA)

Is this is a bug or an intension? Can the type inference be prevented for generic classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional. The `extends` clause of a generic type (in this case `T`) only specifies a **constraint** to the passed type.

The type `{ a: number }` does fulfill the constraint because `b` is optional.

```
type T0 = { a: number } extends MyType ? true : false
// -> true
```

When it *successfully* fulfills the constraint, the type `{ a: number }` will become the type `T` (without inheriting `MyType`). Since `b` is not part of `{ a: number }`, you get an error.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is there any way to prevent inference? The use case is that `a` and `b` are some options. If either option is not passed, the default value is used. But it is possible to set all the options later. Child classes can introduce additional options. Thus, a generic class.

Comment: Are you sure that you need generics in this case? Why not just use `MyType` instead of `T`?

Comment: `MyClass` is part of a JS library. The users of the library need to be able to extend the class and options. Here's an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkEsCMCcENYE8BQkB2AXAprAZvAMbYQwDyADppAPboDOoA3qPAPwBco6ArgLbRcAGlDRO3foNigAvgG4UKQgBt49RlGgBhVeoA8AFVDYAHjnQATDeSq0GoALylolanXoA+ZilC-Qhd0xYHkJMGlgACkwuAwBKZhkfPz5sTAALGgsomPimRMSlQNBlR25sAHdnHTV6CJZ4LgBGWViFZQA6FPTMutEmloUUEFAAVXpcNCxcAmJR8dhXO0ZTcytnRfdvP39xXgEJ+UUVGrncavVjM2xLa21dej0x3A2GLyYUAoCGTFAeUvQKqdYOdaixCP0ZK0UDxOqkMlkWNAIVCgA).

Comment: @Roman - Maybe you want something like this: https://tsplay.dev/Nr4yDW

Comment: This kind of work but in reality there is a lot of methods that would need to be fixed this way.  Plus there is [another issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PTAEBkEsCMCcENYE8BQkB2AXAprAZvAMbYQwDyADppAPboDOoA3qPAPwBco6ArgLbRcAGlDRO3foNigAvgG4UKQgBt49RlGgBhVeoA8AFVDYAHjnQATDeSq0GoALylolanXoA+ZilC-Qhd0xYHkJMGlgACkwuAwBKZhkfPz5sTAALGgsorgAFRGp4ZT0cyEIAa0MRMuwkGjxnVztPLwAyUDI+SExK0Gra+s1G9w94pkTEpUDQZUdubAB3Zx01egiWeC4ARllYhWUAOhT0zLXRLZ2FSYZMUVn0BaXdVfWtkUJzmV2UaEPUjKyXqBNiJoK9-B8vj8jv9ThsgRdQCBQAADQjI0TYAIpVhzRawbAARx4kHxFlAFFgNAouEwSCAA)  with inference.

Comment: if the answer to my second question is **no** (it can not be prevented) please update your answer with that info and I am happy to accept it.

Comment: @Roman - What if you make sub-classes generic too? https://tsplay.dev/WYZyvw   Passing an explicit generic type when you instantiate the class would prevent inference. This works as long as you don't want to infer additional properties passed to the constructor.

Comment: Yes, that will work. In our case, this is a breaking change, so we have to wait for the major release and then instruct our users to always provide an explicit generic type. The goal was to make the generic type optional and not to introduce a breaking change. Here's the original [issue](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/pull/1730). Thank you @Tobias.